# How to fix errors on http put request on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to authenticate using the below code and unable to succeed. It looks like the json structure is incorrect.

I've tried to check the same on native android using kotlin and it works correctly.

below are the logs

```
flutter: {data: {email: nelloresec@xxx.com, password: xxx}}
flutter: "{\"errors\":[]}"
flutter: http://xxx.xxx.xx
flutter: Instance of 'Response'
flutter: 400
flutter: {errors: []}
```

Comment: Looking at body, it looks like your authentication server accepts json. But you are not setting correpsonding header. `httpClient.post` takes headers argument. Pass `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `content-type` for a body of types `String`, `List<int>` or  `Map<String, String>` is `'text/plain'` and I guess you want `'application/json'`

In addition you can directly pass in the user object to the body paramater (as toJson will be invoked automatically by the `json.encode()`-function).

Lastly, you don't need to use both `await` and `.then(...)`, `await` will suffice:

```
void userLogin(String url, User user) async {
  http.Response response = await http.put(
    '$url/api/login',
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    },
    body: json.encode(user),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    print(json.encode(response.body));
    print(url);
    print(response);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    throw Exception("Error while fetching data");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :)

As mentioned using headers was essentials

headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    },